QML - Generate a TreeView based on a ListModel
For a project based on Qt 6.8, QML, and Python, I would like to create a custom component that displays data from a ListModel in a TreeView format. I know that a TreeView component already exists in QML, but it requires a model generated in the backend (Python in my case), which limits my application too much. I would like to dynamically add data to my ListModel, and have that data displayed in my TreeView. Additionally, this way of loading data would be more consistent with the other data loaded in my application. The ListModel would look like this:
ListModel {
    ListElement { itemId: 1; itemName: "Parent 1"; parentId: null }
    ListElement { itemId: 2; itemName: "Child 1"; parentId: 1 }
    ListElement { itemId: 3; itemName: "Child 2"; parentId: 1 }
    ListElement { itemId: 4; itemName: "Parent 2"; parentId: null }
    ListElement { itemId: 5; itemName: "Parent 3"; parentId: 4 }
    ListElement { itemId: 6; itemName: "Child 3"; parentId: 5 }
}

My basic idea was to display each piece of data in a Repeater, with an indentation level calculated to indicate the hierarchy between the data. Now, I would like to integrate a button system to show or hide the children of a data item, as well as a checkbox for each data item. This checkbox would allow, for a data item without children, to select it and add it to a list of selected data, and for a data item with children, to select all its children at once and add them to the list.
Here is my current code, as well as an example of how to call the component in a main.qml file:
main.qml:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Item {
    id: item
    width: 300
    height: 500
    TreeViewCustom {
        id: treeView
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}

TreeViewCustom.qml:
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ColumnLayout {
    property var dataModel: ListModel {
        ListElement { itemId: 1; itemName: "Parent 1"; parentId: null }
        ListElement { itemId: 2; itemName: "Child 1"; parentId: 1 }
        ListElement { itemId: 3; itemName: "Child 2"; parentId: 1 }
        ListElement { itemId: 4; itemName: "Parent 2"; parentId: null }
        ListElement { itemId: 5; itemName: "Parent 3"; parentId: 4 }
        ListElement { itemId: 6; itemName: "Child 3"; parentId: 5 }
    }
    spacing: 0

    function getIndentationLevel(itemId) {
        var level = -1
        var currentItemId = itemId

        while (true) {
            var parentFound = false
            for (var i = 0; i < dataModel.count; i++) {
                var element = dataModel.get(i)
                if (element.itemId === currentItemId) {
                    if (element.parentId === null) {
                        return level
                    } else {
                        currentItemId = element.parentId
                        level++
                        parentFound = true
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!parentFound) {
                break
            }
        }
        return level
    }

    Repeater {
        model: dataModel
        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 40

            RowLayout {
                spacing: 0
                Rectangle {
                    height: parent.height
                    width: 20 * getIndentationLevel(model.itemId)
                    color: "transparent"
                }
                LabelCustom {
                    text: model.itemId + " - " + model.itemName
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

How to modify this code to add those features, especially the button to show/hide children of a node ? I'm stuck with unsuccessful attempts.
Thanks for your time !

what is your question?

how to modify this code to add those features, especially the button to show/hide children of a node ? I'm stuck with unsuccessful attempts. sorry if my question wasn't precise enough, this is the first time I post a question here

why not just use standard controls that provide all these features? using the model, you can sort and filter the data source and it will look in some standard way for the target system. It looks like you're just trying to reinvent the wheel.

you mean by using a QAbstractItemModel declared in Python ?

in principle, yes. I do not know how this is done in Python, I write mainly in C++, but I think that provides a similar option.

i was trying to avoid using python (backend in general) to handle the data of my treeview, because my application has to send a lot of form fields data to the backend directly to save them via SQL query execution, and I would like to send the TreeView selected data to the same function. I will keep trying to make it work with the native component, but i doubt it suits my needs
